# Melhor forma para descobrir se o usuário está online/offline

Tags: php, javascript

Bom, estou com as páginas de login e home, ao realizar o login o usuário é setado como online no BD e é levado à home, na home, ao clicar no botão de logout o usuário é setado como offline e levado ao login.

Até aí tudo bem, porém, ao o usuário clicar para fechar a janela ou o navegador quero que ele seja setado como offline no BD. Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ter esse tipo de coisa dependendo de uma interação com o usuário não é uma boa ideia, se o computador desligar repentinamente (faltar energia, forçar desligamento porque travou, etc) os dados no banco não serão atualizados

Imagino que, no banco, você tenha uma coluna `online` em que é setado true ou false, sugiro que mude para um tipo data (`datetime` ou `timestamp`), quando o usuário logar seja setado, nesse campo, a data atual mais um intervalo de 5min, por exemplo. No frontend crie um `setInterval` que faça uma requisição ajax a cada 5min para atualizar novamente o campo. Se um `setInterval` não for possível, pode ser feito essa atualização no banco sempre que o usuário realiza alguma requisição para o backend, desse modo, os dados do banco ficaram desatualizados por, no máximo, 5min

Mas cuidado, dependendo de quantos usuários tiverem usando a aplicação ao mesmo tempo, pode tornar a aplicação muito pesada

Como não especificou qual banco está usando, imaginei que seja um SQL como o MySQL